# How to record audio from an application/audio device?

Tags: itunes, audio, recording

My nephew is gonna be on the radio tonight. I'd like to record the stream either from iTunes or from my web browser.

What are my options to accomplish that?

Comment: The single best app for doing this is [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) It's not cheap for a one-trick pony, but there's nothing better. It has a trial period, so you might get away with just that, but the trial lays noise over recordings longer than 10 mins.

Comment: The question is, you said he was going to be on the "radio."  Is this Internet radio or terrestrial (regular FM) radio?  If terrestrial, do they stream on the Internet and how so?  The more information you can provide the better.  There may even be free options depending on the situation and your skill level.

Comment: What hardware do you have? (Which would help is choose iOS vs PC vs Mac type software or accessories )

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](http://videolan.org) has an option for listening to network streams, so if VLC is compatible with the stream that you want to listen to it also offers an option for saving that stream to your HD. In the dialog box that lets you enter the stream URL there is a drop down menu by the OPEN button that lets you save the stream.

Of course this does depend on if VLC will open the specific stream you want it to. Many streaming services use special players and DRM to prevent such things. Failing the VLC method Tetsujin has an excellent recommendation in Audio Hijack as it doesn't care about any of that and just records all the audio passing through your Mac.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of any recording feature in iTunes for Internet radios. Check if the specific radio station has a webpage/webstream and you might be able to record that via your standard audio recorder in the OS of your choice.
If you have access to an iOS device, the app Audials has a recording option and it's free of charge.

Comment: Try expanding your answer to include more information, links to the recommended software and ensuring it is relevant to the OP's question; in this case iTunes/browser.